# SQL Select distinct output of two columns in one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle as below.

```
COMPANY  BUSINESS   CONTACT1          CONTACT2
ABC        CL       email1@abc.com    email2@abc.com
ABC        YM       email1@abc.com    email3@abc.com
ABC        ZF       email4@abc.com    email1@abc.com
XYZ        CL       email1@xyz.com    email2@xyz.com
XYZ        YM       email3@xyz.com    email1@xyz.com
GEF        CL       email1@gef.com    email2@gef.com
```

I want to select the distinct COMPANY and CONTACT1 and CONTACT2 in single row seperated by , as below

OUTPUT:

```
COMPANY      CONTACT
ABC          email1@abc.com,email2@abc.com,email3@abc.com,email4@abc.com
XYZ          email1@xyz.com,email2@xyz.com,email3@xyz.com
GEF          email1@gef.com,email2@gef.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with
     inputs ( company, business, contact1, contact2 ) as (
       select 'ABC', 'CL', 'email1@abc.com', 'email2@abc.com' from dual union all
       select 'ABC', 'YM', 'email1@abc.com', 'email3@abc.com' from dual union all
       select 'ABC', 'ZF', 'email4@abc.com', 'email1@abc.com' from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', 'CL', 'email1@xyz.com', 'email2@xyz.com' from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', 'YM', 'email3@xyz.com', 'email1@xyz.com' from dual union all
       select 'GEF', 'CL', 'email1@gef.com', 'email2@gef.com' from dual
     )
-- end of test data; SQL solution begins below this line
select company, listagg(email, ',') within group (order by email) as email_list
from   (
         select distinct company, email
         from   inputs
         unpivot (email for col in (contact1, contact2))
       )
group by company
;

COMPANY   EMAIL_LIST
-------   --------------------------------------------------------
ABC       email1@abc.com,email2@abc.com,email3@abc.com,email4@abc.com
GEF       email1@gef.com,email2@gef.com
XYZ       email1@xyz.com,email2@xyz.com,email3@xyz.com
```

Comment: that is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT company , listagg(emails, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY emails) as emails
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT company, contact1 AS emails FROM yourtable
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT company, contact2  AS emails  FROM yourtable
) tt
GROUP BY company
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to SELECT **DISTINCT**; UNION de-duplicates the results anyway. The difference between our solutions is the way I use UNPIVOT. The benefit may not be immediately obvious; it is the fact that UNPIVOT only reads the base table once, while the UNION approach requires the base table to be read twice (resulting in more I/O, which is expensive).